# How to Open a UIViewController on Click of UIButton In UIView

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistoryboard

I wants to open a UIViewController on Click of UIButton which is inside a **UIView**.
The **UIView** has it's own **.h & .m** file & The action property of button is declared inside the it.

the navigation code is working fine if I am calling it from UIViewController of UIbutton which is like

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
FilterDemoTableViewController *viewController = (FilterDemoTableViewController*)     [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:  @"FilterDemoTableViewController_Id"];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

but if same code is calling from UIView .m file then it's not working plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

And it won't. You can't call `[self navigationController]` inside `UIView` because it doesn't have one.

All you have to do is to reference the ViewController that **owns** your `UIView` and call a method there.

Typically, you can do it with `NSNotification` - not the best way but definitely works.